# How to be sure a Firebase user was deleted

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know there are quite a few questions around this, but mine is a bit different.

Here is the scenario:

- I create a user in my iOS app, in Firebase
- I delete the user in Firebase
- 10 days later I start my app

How can I know the user has been deleted?

What happens right now is:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser != nil
```

because my app/Firebase caches the user

Next I call:

```
user.reload { error in ... }
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Optional<Error>
  - some : Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000026f2be0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN";
}}}}
```

So clearly the refresh token is no longer in use ( --> 400 ).

However, how can I tell the difference between "this token is no longer valid because it hasn't been used in ages" vs "this token is no longer valid because this user no longer exists"?

I could react to any error here by asking the user to sign in again, but there could be other errors, not related to the account itself, e.g. when the connection to the Firebase server can't be made?

Is there a specific list of error codes which I should consider "ask the user to log in again"?
Is there a bullet-proof way of handling this?

Thanks

edit:

this is the code I use to monitor user changes

```
class StartViewModel: ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var hasAuthenticatedUser: Bool = false
    @Published var isRefreshing: Bool = false
    
    var user: User! {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != nil && user == nil {
                self.hasAuthenticatedUser = false
            }
            if oldValue == nil && user != nil {
                self.hasAuthenticatedUser = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var listenerHandle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle!
    
    init() {
        listenerHandle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] _, user in
            if let self = self {
                self.user = user
            }
        }
        
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            self.isRefreshing = true
            self.user = Auth.auth().currentUser
            user.reload { error in
             // Here I get the 400 error
            }
        }
    }
```

edit:

Here something extra I discovered. App hasn't run for weeks and the user does no longer exist on Firebase side. This is the code that I ran:

```
        listenerHandle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] _, user in
            if let self = self {
                
                if user != nil {
                    debugPrint("Has authenticated user")
                } else {
                    debugPrint("Does not have authenticated user")
                }
```

The logger shows me:

```
Has authenticated user
```

immediately followed by

```
Does not have authenticated user
```

How can I be sure the user that I got in the first call actually exists? I build my user interface depending on whether there is a user or not, and it just pingpongs between "ah yes" and "NOPE" in a fraction of a second.

Comment: 1) "What happens right now is: `Auth.auth().currentUser != nil`" That should not be happening after 10 days, as the ID token is only valid for an hour. Can you show the more completely code of where you run this check? 2) In general, it is recommended to use a listener as shown in the first snippet in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: Are you saying that if I kill the app for longer than an hour that currentUser will always be nil? I just added more code

Comment: You should not explicitly have to `reload` the user in the `addStateDidChangeListener`. Your ID token (and based on that the user) will get auto-refresh, which is actually when your `addStateDidChangeListener` callback gets called to begin with.

Comment: I don't call the reload inside the listener, but in the init of the class containing the listener. I suppose the listener isn't automatically called once upon creation?

Comment: The listener **is** called: 1) right after you attach it, with whatever the current state is in the client, 2) whenever that state changes. As you can see, I'm really struggling to understand the problem you're having, and feel this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you show a single snippet that I can run to reproduce the problem, preferably something that prints the unexpected value that you're asking about?

Comment: Ok I'll see what I can do

Comment: I discovered something else @FrankvanPuffelen. I run my Firebase environment locally. It was completely reset and I didn't run the app I am developing for weeks. I just started it up and what happens is that Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener sends me a user object (of a previous session weeks ago) and immediately afterwards sends me a nil user object. So I can't trust it since it says "there is a user" and then immediately "Ah no sorry, there isn't" to be sure the user exists for the app. How can I solve this?

Comment: I added the info in an edit to the original question